# Date range filter in OOTB for SPListview

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, filter, query-string, date

I am working on a project in SharePoint 2013.

Currently I am trying to implement list view filtering using OOTB `QueryString` parameters.

I have found the following params have been working a treat when dealing with a multiple condition: `FilterField1, FilterValue1, FilterOp1 ,FilterField2, FilterValue2, FilterOp2 etc`

I've tried this approach which worked. But when I am having multiple pages, it broken up the list & does not shows any items even though there are multiple items.

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Can you add the URL that is not working?